# SQL: Invalid column name after table updated

Tags: sql

If I run the code below it gives invalid column name. It also gives problems later down in my code.

```
ALTER TABLE #final
ADD DOB2 DATE

UPDATE #final 
SET DOB = '1980-01-01' where DOB ='NULL'

UPDATE #final 
SET DOB2 = CAST(DOB as date)
```

Any reason why? I've already tried CTRL + SHIFT + R

Thank you!

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 1):

T-SQL (which I presume you are using) compiles lines in batches.  A batch is determined by GO boundaries.  The problem is the code is compiled before the first statement is executed, so `DOB2` is not known during the compile phase -- it hasn't been added yet.

You can easily fix this by adding `GO`:

```
ALTER TABLE #final ADD DOB2 DATE
GO

UPDATE #final 
    SET DOB = '1980-01-01' 
    WHERE DOB = 'NULL'

UPDATE #final 
    SET DOB2 = CAST(DOB as date);
```

I'm not sure what `DOB = 'NULL'` is supposed to be doing.  Dates should be stored using the `DATE` data type.  The `DATE` data type does not store string values, such as `'NULL'`.  Perhaps you intend `WHERE DOB IS NULL`.